# NoReverseMatch at /portal

Tags: python, django

I am still trying to find out why the same line of code works in Apache 2.2.22 with mod_wsgi and causes an error with any other version such as 2.2.25 and 2.4. When I run the python/django app under 2.2.22, no errors, no complaints, no loss of functionality. When I change the Apache to be 2.2.25 (or 2.4) I get the following error messages from Django ...

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1/portal/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'account_index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 424
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\httpd.exe
```

Referring to these lines ...

```
48  {% if user.is_superuser %}
49  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'account_index' %}">Browse</a></li>
50  {% else %}
```

This is the only piece that causes an error and I have no explanation as to why. The link next to it is exactly the same and causes no errors. I have checked the Apache logs, there is no complaint about wsgi failures. The Django error message gives me no more info than above. I am very confused about this as going to the html template file and removing line #49 eliminates the error (but also the dropdown menu).

*** Looking at related posts about similar errors gave me the idea that this line from account.urls.py might be the problem, can anyone comment on this?

```
url(r'^/?$', 'account.views.account_index', name='account_index'),
```

Comment: Looking at related posts about similar errors gave me the idea that this line from account.urls.py might be the problem, can anyone comment on this?

Comment: I would start debugging by checking if the sys.path of both installations is identical.